# magento 1.9.1 invoice mails sent through cron?

Tags: php, magento, cron, invoice, magento-1.9.1

I have magento 1.9.1 installation. Everything is working fine, order are getting placed, new order emails are going through email queue and my cron is also working fine.

Issue is while submitting **invoice** from admin panel (clicking checkbox 'Email Copy of Invoice') it is taking lot of time because invoice email is send here . **I want to schedule it with cron.** Its seems to me magento didnot provide this functionality yet or may be I am worng.

Someone please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is true! Since Magento 1.9 all transactional emails are being sent via Cron and Invoice emails are some of them.  You can read more [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron).

But anyway it should not take more than five minutes: if it takes longer than that you need to dig more. [This](http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob#My_cronjob_doesn.27t_work._What_can_I_do.3F) wiki might help for that purpose.